# como agrego la autorizacion en esta peticion para que funciones

Tags: python, python-requests

Estoy haciendo una peticion http en python pero para que la peticion funcione necesita una autorizacion que tendria que agregar en mi coigo para meter la autorizacion

Adjunto codigo:

```
´´´import requests

 class metodos():
def request(metodo):
    url = input("ingrese la url: https://")
    if url != "":
        if metodo == "GET":
            response = requests.get('https://'+url)
            print('status:',response.status_code)
        else:
            print('No se pintado ninguna url')
  metodos.request('GET')´´´
```

Se que va el parametro de autoriazacion pero en que parte iria para que funcione la peticion ycomo tendria que ponerlo y que tendria que poner para que funcione la peticion estoy usando python y la libreria requests

Comment: agregas el parámetro `auth` y el contenido depende del tipo de autorización

Comment: ok eso lo pondria en que parte

Comment: Al hacer la petición, va como parámetro de la función `get`

Comment: va si fucnion gracias